# Jquery UI Accordion get sortable ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is fiddle basically the same thing as seen on [jquery](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable)

Here is fiddle of that version: http://jsfiddle.net/DHCaA/

What I am trying to do is simple. For example (using that fiddle) If I move section 1 below section 2, how can I get ID's of the sections that switched place. I need those ID's so I can do some calculations and changes on my model.

Every element in the accordion is created dynamically, and I can create whatever I desire. For example:

```
<div id ="first-1" class="group">
```

Thats first entry with ID.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store the original index of the elements(e.g. via `data()`) and after a sort compare the stored index and the current index(when they are not equal the position has changed). After that update the stored index.

```
$( "#accordion" )
      .accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        collapsible: true
      })
      .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var items=[];
        ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function(){
            //compare data('index') and the real index
            if($(this).data('index')!=$(this).index()){
              items.push(this.id);
            }
          });
          // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
          // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
          ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
          if(items.length)alert(items.join(','));
          ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
        }
      }).on('stop',function(){
        $(this).children().each(function(i){$(this).data('index',i)});
      }).trigger('stop');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHCaA/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
function current_order(el){
    var order=[];
    el.children().each( function(i){      
              order[i]=this.id;
    });
    // silly test      
    for(var i=0; i<order.length; i++){
       console.log("got " + order[i]);
   }
}
```

// added to the accordian stop method

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
      // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
      // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
      ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );

      current_order($(this));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
.sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: "h3",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var items=[];
        ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each( function(){
            //compare data('index') and the real index
            if($(this).data('index')!=$(this).index()){
                items.push(this.id);
            }
        });
        // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
        // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
        ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
        **if(items.length) $("#sequence").text(items.join(','));**
        ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
    } 
})
```

Below the accordian I list the sequence with

```
<div>
    Sequence:  <span id="sequence"> This is the sequence of the elements.</span>
</div>
```